# Oracle JDK Public Updates till 01/31/2019 or 01/01/2019?

Tags: java, oracle

According to [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html): “Oracle will continue to provide Public Updates and auto updates of Java SE 8, until at least the end of December 2020 for Personal Users, and *January 2019* for Commercial Users.” My reading from this statement is that Java 8 will be supported till **end** of January.

However, when I checked on Azul’s website, the last free Oracle Java 8 update in in 147 days putting the Oracle JDK support at 12/31/2018.

Which is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is January 15, 2019.  Here is a link to their [website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alerts-086861.html).

Answer (score 1):

The date (month) given only implies you shouldn't expect a public release after that date.  This doesn't mean they plan to do a release at around that time (update 192 might be the last), nor does it prevent them from doing a release for critical fixes after that date.

OpenJDK 8 update 172 was released in April 2018 http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/releases/8u172.html

and update 192 will be released in October 2018 http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/releases/8u192.html

NOTE: Oracle don't specify a day of the month so the last day of December might be a reasonable estimate for a specific day.